# Add Link to a line in Code vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

we have a bit of code with "To Do" comments. Was wondering if there is a way to create a document either in VS or Word where I can describe what is planned and then create a hyperlink of some sort to the VB code?

Comment: Menu `View` -> `Task List`. Comments that start with `TODO` will be shown there.

Comment: This sounds interesting. I do have a few comments that begin with TODO but they do not show up on task list. Going to google it

NVM: Changed it to Comments task list and it all appeared :)! THanks

Comment: If you post that under, I can mark is an answered?

Comment: I added it as answer :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio has this already integrated. Go to the menu `View` and select there the item `Task List` (might be under a subnode `Other Windows`).

The Task List will be now shown. Make sure you select "Comments" in the drop down, to see all `TODO`'s from the comments.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `file://` URIs in comments. VS will (by default) make URIs in code clickable unless you turn it off (Tools > Options > Text Editor > $language > Enable single-click URL navigation).

Comment: I think he wants the other way around.

Comment: @Styxxy derp! sorry :/